# Php. Какие ошибки в коде?

Tags: php, архитектура

Всем привет. 
Какие ошибки есть в коде?  Архитектура, оформление и т.д.
https://github.com/Vladbara705/task
SQL можно не смотреть.
Задача была: 
Есть купюры в банкомате, нужно запросить сумму и выдать ее, если сумма не больше,чем имеется в банкомате и, если купюры позволяют это сделать. Так же, нужно обновлять оставшиеся купюры в банкомате.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что код-ревью должен проводиться непосредственным лидом вашей команды либо вашим ментором.

Answer (score 1):

Если уж озаботились интерфейсами, то покрывайте ими а) конечные классы б) все публичные методы

А у вас получается `class Bankomat implements Atm`, который нигде напрямую не используется, зато основной класс `Calculations extends Bankomat` имеет кучу публичных методов и вообще непонятно, зачем ему наследованный интерфейс `Atm`

Answer (score 0):

На счет оформления, каждый класс должен быть в отдельном файле. [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#3-namespace-and-class-names)